# Postscript image output wrong on some color models

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, color-space

I have written a C code to generate postscript files from PWG raster files. The output is working on (format is color model - bit depth): black-1, black-8, black-16, rgb-8, rgb-16, gray-1, gray-8, gray-16, srgb-8, srgb-16, adobergb-8, sgray-1, sgray-8, cmyk-1, cmyk-8, cmyk-16.
But the output of adobergb-16 and sgray-16 given is wrong. I get the pattern similar to the input file but the colors are all pixelated.

Actual code is very big, so I am posting what I did:

```
take all the image pixels in an unsigned char* variable (this sometimes becomes very large)

encode the pixels using deflate algorithm from zlib

display the result
```

For adobergb-16 I am setting PS colorspace to `/DeviceRGB` and the decode array is `/Decode [0 1 0 1 0 1]`.
For sgray-16 I am setting the PS colorspace to `/DeviceGray` and the decode is `/Decode [0 1]`
These setting are similar to adobergb-8 and sgray-8.

EDIT 1:
Adding the example files I used to test [HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-wSviYjd5oCd3NoN1lScVdDWlE)

If you want any further information or the code snippets, please feel free to ask.

Comment: No version of PostScript supports 16-bit image data on input (caveat, non-standard extensions exist). The highest available BitsPerComponent in PostScript is 12. If you are trying to wedge 16-bit data into a 12-bit (or 8 bit ?) colour space, its hardly surprising that the result is not what you expect. If you are treating a 16-bit value as 2 8-bit values, then every 2nd pixel will be visibly incorrect.  If you want any help on this you are going to have to post an example. Make a nice simple small example and post a link to it.

Comment: @KenS I have posted the the example files. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you've set "/BitsPerComponent 16"; as I said above, that's not a legal value, since PostScript only supports 1, 2, 4, 8 and 12 bits per component.

Running this file through Adobe Acrobat Distiller gives:

%%[ Error: rangecheck; OffendingCommand: imageDistiller; ErrorInfo: BitsPerComponent 16 ]%%

Rewriting your image like this:

```
gsave
/DeviceRGB setcolorspace
/Input currentfile /FlateDecode filter def
4958 7017 scale
<< 
/ImageType 1
/Width 4958
/Height 7017
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Decode [0 1 0 1 0 1]
/DataSource {3 string 0 1 2 {1 index exch Input read {pop}if Input read pop put } for} bind
/ImageMatrix [4958 0 0 -7017 0 7017]
>> image
```

Sets the BitsPerComponent to 8, discards the top byte of every 16-bit value, and the output works as expected.

When I said 'a nice simple small example' I didn't mean 30 MB of data, that is not necessary to exhibit the problem I am certain. When posting examples make a simple, small, example and use that. I haven't bothered to download your other files.

To reiterate; **you cannot set /BitsPerComponent 16, PostScript does not support 16 bits per component.**

Comment: But won't the discarding of top byte of every 16-bit value degrade the quality of output?

Comment: Well, yes,obviously. The point was to show that there was nothing actually wrong with the image data. Your problem is simply that you **cannot** declare a PostScript image as containing 16 BitsPerComponent. So if you want to deal with that, you are going to have to downsample the colour data. You can do it in your program in C, or in the PostScript program, as I demonstrated (simplistically) above.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. May I ask you, how do you know so much about postscript ?

Comment: You already know the answer to that, I work for a company that produces a PostScript interpreter. And the reason they employ me is because I have done so (at different places) for the last 20 years.......

Comment: Can you please tell me what does `1 index exch` does above. Can't get it

Comment: If you want to program PostScript, you're going to have to learn PostScript. See the PostScript Language Reference Manual for details on the operation of all PostScript operators.